# UIActivityViewController not passing new line characters to some activities

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, whatsapp

I am using the following code to set up UIActivityViewController:

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self textMessageToShare], nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            if (completed) {
                [self sendFeedbackWithIndexPath:indexPath AndLikeType:100 AndCell:nil];
            }
        }];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                                animated:YES
                                              completion:^{
                                                  // ...
                                              }];
```

Issue is that when I copy a message or post to facebook or twitter or email or gmail app or to default Messages app, the new line characters that are in `[self textMessageToShare]` are maintained. However, if I share to other activities like WhatsApp or Viber - all the new line characters are removed, and the whole message is sent as one single line.

Whereas, if I share just text through iOS default Notes app, new line characters are maintained when shared to these apps. How would the Notes app be storing the new line characters? I am using `\n` as the new line character.

For my life unable to even find the reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: tried both \\n \r.. same result

Comment: It probably depends on the app's share extension to see if it allows newline.

Comment: @Schemetrical It allows - as I mentioned in the question, default Notes app's new lines get passed through.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see that. Try inserting a [newline character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) manually, replacing the `\n`s.

Comment: @Schemetrical I tried replacing `\n` with `\xA` (if that what you meant), but same results. Donno what is wrong here 

Comment: no one with any clue?

Comment: @BufferStack you get new line or not.. same issue with me ... so help me plz..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make it work by converting the newline characters to `"<br/>"`:

```
_myDataString=  self.textview.text;
_myDataString= [_myDataString  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
```

Comment: Hey this is superb!! This does solves the issue. But now the other activities - which take \n as new line character are printing `<br/>`. Could you also find a way to selectively apply br replacement for only those activities that follow it?

Comment: i try with this=>                    NSString *strRemove = [textToShare  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@"    \n\n\n"];
but not getting new line in whats app textfield..

Answer (score 2):

Please check the new line issue in whats app share using uiactivityviewcontroller.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShareActivity : UIActivityItemProvider

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *activities;

@end


#import "ShareActivity.h"

@implementation ShareActivity
@synthesize message = _message;
@synthesize activities = _activities;

 - (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController     *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
if([activityType    isEqualToString:@"net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"])
{
return [self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
}
else if ([self.activities containsObject:activityType]) 
{
return [self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
}
else 
{
    return self.message;
}
return nil;
}

- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController 
{ 
return @"";
}
```

In View Controller Class on any action button to pop up the share view
Apply this action on any button action

```
-(void)shareAction
{
ShareActivity *shareObj = [[ShareActivity alloc] initWithPlaceholderItem:@""];

NSString *message = @"New\nLine\nText\nMessage";
[shareObj setMessage:message];

NSArray* dataToShare = @[shareObj];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
{

NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;
if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent!";
}
else if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Post on twitter, ok!";
}
else if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Post on facebook, ok!";
}
else if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Message copy to pasteboard";
}
else if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFlickr] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Message sent to flickr";
}
else if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToVimeo] )
{
ServiceMsg = @"Message sent to Vimeo";
}
else
{

}

}];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? Also try to be as precise in answers as possible.

Comment: If we add accepted answer line then whats app activity issue will resolve but add the br/ character in other activities like facebook,imessage ,notes etc.

Comment: This is the better answer, because it considers the different sharing end points.

Answer (score 0):

hi its me again i was looking for the right answer

and i found that you can do it by using a Custom Share Message to Different Providers .

and you can find an example from this Code check for MyActivityItemProvider class .

https://github.com/apascual/flip-your-phone

i hove a problem posting the code here so i think the link above will help

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as links can go stale. Could you put the relevant part in the body of your answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MuslimDev2015 I have been able to develop a solution:
https://github.com/lorenzoPrimi/NewlineActivityItemProvider

Try it and let me know.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the text as multiple items each item is just one line.

```
let lines = text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: lines, applicationActivities: nil)
```